# 'Make' error - glib.h no such file or directory

Tags: makefile, glib

I have never built a project in Ubuntu before and I am trying to come to grips with the GNU build tools and process.

When I try to make I get the `glib.h - no such file or directory`.

This is the output of `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0`

```
-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include  -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lglib-2.0
```

I presume the above output are the compiler flags make uses?

Any ideas?

Comment: What software are you compiling - it may help us provide a more solid answer

Answer (score 9):

It appears that `gcc` can't find the `glib.h` which is a part of the `libglib2.0-dev` package. Make sure you've installed `libgtk2.0-0-dev` package (which depends on `libglib2.0-dev`) and try again.

Comment: I have libgtk2.0-dev installed.

Comment: emmm, I'm installed the libgtk2.0-0-dev library and not work, appear the message:
glib-gprint.c:24:18: error fatal: glib.h: no such file or directory for any question I'm got xubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 4):

You need to tell `make` to use `pkg-config` to find out the compiler flags. Like so

```
CFLAGS = `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0` 
LDLIBS = `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0`
```

`make` will execute `pkg-config` and use the output to fill in `CFLAGS` and `LDLIBS`

Comment: Perfectly explained, it worked for me.

Comment: How can i add this to cmake file i.e. CMakeLists.txt ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `pkg-config --cflags --libs  glib-2.0` in make file.
It should look like this:

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` file.c
```

Comment: tried adding that to the beginning and end of my Makefile, got something like this (only line number changes) both times: `Makefile:17: *** missing separator.  Stop.`